# Google Chrome doesn't allow storage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

In order to save grid configurations and some simple settings, I use localStorage.

It works on many browsers except on Google Chrome.

By the way, it doesn't work on pcs which are under our local domain.

On the same network, on a PC not under the domain, it works.

Any idea, please?

Here is whet I do (I use Devextreme datagrid's standard functions and I have the same result) :

```
     function toggleCustomerRightPanel(state) {
        if (state) {
            $("#customerRightBar").animate({ width: "show" });
            localStorage.setItem("capronCrmActionBar", state);
            $("body").css("margin-right", "250px");
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("capronCrmActionBar");
            $("#customerRightBar").animate({ width: "hide" });
            $("body").css("margin-right", "0px");
        }
    }




    function setCustomerActionBarState() {
      if ($("#mainContent").is(":visible") && localStorage.getItem("capronCrmActionBar")=="true") {
         $("body").css("margin-right", "250px");
      }
      else {
         $("body").css("margin-right", "0px");
      }
    }
```

When I change something on the application, I see on Chrome storing the data. For exemple :

[image]

But, when I close the browser and reopen it, the data is cleared.
For exemple on Opera or Firefox, it works.

Comment: I checked all extensions, there are only the google's own extensions, even I disabled them. The same result.

Comment: there's a setting in chrome `Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome` - you probably have that set

Comment: Checked it also, I allowed cookies and clear cookies and site data is not toggled.

Comment: go to settings, type `clear cookies and site data when you quit chrome` select the highlited option - disable that option

Comment: It is already disabled.

Comment: Can it be the antivirus program ?

Comment: why would it effect chrome and not other browsers? so this is every site, or just some sites (i.e. just yours)?

Comment: Can't see the "capronCrmActionBar" key in localStorage. Are you sure it reflects on change?

Another thing worth checking, though quite unlikely, is are you crossing the localStorage size limit?

Comment: In fact, I don't know if other applications can store data. I see passwords and usernames when I open my application or another site. I believe there is only a problem with localStorage.

Comment: #Ashfaque Ahmad Bari,  I can see on google chrome any storage key that I store while the browser is open. When I close it and reopen, they disappear.  But on other browsers, they stays and it works.